# ¿Cómo pasar un parámetro desde el home a otro controlador?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, mvc

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les explico lo siguiente:

El controlador 2 actualmente si ingresas un parámetro precarga cierta data relacionada a ése parámetro ingresado.

Ahora me solicitan que desde el home ingresen dicho parámetro como muestra el #2 de la imagen y pasarle dicho parámetro al controlador del #3 de la imagen.

Se usa como lenguaje ASP MVC 4, por ahora no encuentro la manera de realizar ese pase pues siempre desde el home buscara el formato controlador/vista (patrón MVC) y por ende da 404.

Hay alguna de momento para mí ninguna.

Acá el route config para el #3 de la imagen.

```
   routes.MapRoute( _
       name:="Registro", _
       url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
       defaults:=New With {.controller = "Usuario", .action = "InsertarUsuario", .pv = UrlParameter.Optional} _
   )
```

Comment: Queres pasar información de controlador a controlador o de una vista a un controlador?

Comment: Hola, se desea recibir el parámetro por URL, pero al añadirle /valor da error 404, ese es el asunto.

Comment: Pero queres acceder al controlador desde la vista o desde otro controlador? (Nota: Tenés experiencia en la arquitectura?)

Comment: Lo que quiero es recibir el parámetro desde el controlador del home (landing page con url del #1 de la imagen) usando RouteData.Values("id") para a traves de un redirect o url action para pasarlo a otro controlador (#3 de la imagen).

Comment: ** Me funciono y pude pasar como *string* la llave de mi tabla **padre** del view **Index** del Modelo Padre al **create** del controlador de mi Modelo hijo en una relación de uno a muchos. Gracias Mil. qdtb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pasar información entre controladores lo que debes usar es el TempData, recibes en el controlador del Home y en el controlador que lo necesites lo utilizas.
por ejemplo

```
public ActionResult Index(Objeto obj)
{

    TempData["request1"] = obj.request1;
    return RedirectToAction("About");
}

public ActionResult About() 
{     
    var model= TempData["request1"];     
    return View(); 
}
```

El uso de Tempdata solo te sirve para un request después se borra. Espero te sirva

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos que este código de abajo es una vista, puede pertenecerle a tu controlador Home o a cualquier. Eso no importa:

```
    <div class="row bottomSpace">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Register", "User", new { id = 10 })" class="btn btn_default pull-right btn-success">Registrar Usuario 10</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Si te fijas, puedes usar apoyarte con el método Url.Action, donde el primer parámetro es la acción (método) el segundo es el controlador, y el tercero -en este caso- es un parámetro. Esto es para esta sobrecarga, el método Url.Action tiene multiples sobrecargas.

Puede saber más del URLHelper  [aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505232(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Hola, en este caso el problema no es la vista, sino que desde el home quieren ingresar un parámetro pero al ingresar mydomain.com/parametro da error 404 porque se sale del patrón MVC, la cuestión es como podría controlar eso, o al menos que la url de mi home cargue de una vez el controlador y su vista, así si podría pasar el parámetro utilizando RouteData.Values("id").